# C# - What's are the available multi dimensional data structures that perform well?

Tags: c#, performance, data-structures, c#-4.0, multidimensional-array

I need to store multi-dimensional data consisting of numbers in a manner thats easy to work with. I'm capturing data in **real time** (processing live video frames every 40ms/10ms), and once processed I would destroy and GC older data.

This data structure must be **fast** so it won't hit my overall app performance. The faster the better (my algorithms are pretty time consuming, from 1ms to 20ms and I will be reading / writing this data lots throughout my code).

What are my choices in terms of platform supported data structures? I'm using VS 2010. and .NET 4.

Comment: @Frank - When most people say real time they are really saying *< 1ms*.

Comment: "in a manner thats easy to work with... the faster the better." ... What are you doing with the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way is probably:

- A one-dimensional array, indexed like a multi-dimensional array (`array[x, y]` <=> `array[x + y * columns]`)
- Accessed through pointers if random read/writes occur.
- Reuse the array as much as possible, don't allocate new ones constantly. Especially if it's big, because if the size is > 85K, it gets allocated on the Large Object Heap, which doesn't get compacted by the GC after a collection, causing eventual fragmentation if you constantly reallocate the array.
- Accessed as much as possible in parallel. Just gotta make sure multiple threads never, ever write to the same element.

Of course, this is a generic answer, because the question is also pretty generic. Can't really go wrong with it, though.

Answer (score 1):

Realtime or not, creating an object in .NET is pretty fast, so what about ConcurrentQueue+ tuples?

That way you can read / write thread-safe with pretty standard data structures.
The following code took 3 seconds on my T500 inside Visual Studio with debugging on:

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var q = new ConcurrentQueue<Tuple<int, int, int>>();
Enumerable.Range(0, 10000000).AsParallel().ForAll(i => q.Enqueue(Tuple.Create(i, i, i)));
Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Funny enough, the non-parallel version is even faster.

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple multidimensional array? That seems like the obvious and fastest choice.

Comment: One addition: consider overwriting your values rather than GC'ing the old structures (assuming the structures are the same size).

Comment: Not the fastest... it's slower than a one-dimensional array, and even than a jagged array